# Assigning percentage values to a range of values

Tags: c, arduino

I'm writing an arduino sketch and my sensor is giving values between 400 and 1023.  I want to convert these values into percentages where 400 is 0% and 1023 is 100%.  I've been messing around with various equations, but my algebra's a bit rusty.  Is there an easy way to do this in C?

Answer (score 5):

```
double percentage = (value - 400) / (double) (1023 - 400);
```

This will give you a percentage between 0.0 and 1.0. Multiply by 100 if you want it between 0 and 100.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I assume you can handle the code itself (also, my C is a bit rusty), so I'll explain the math behind the solution:

You basically wanna normalize the values between 400 and 1023.

That's 1023-400 = 623 values to normalize. Our range is 0...623, and we wanna map it to 0...100:

We divide the subtracted value (a number between 0...623) by 623, getting a number between 0...1 (so 0 will be 0, 623 will be 1, and 300 and change will be roughly 0.50), and then you multiply that result by a 100, getting a value between 0...100. And there's your percentage.

Answer (score 1):

### Algebra

```
  0%    <-> 400
  100%  <-> (1023-400)
```

let's say you get a value x = 850

the percentage is:

```
      (850 - 400)/(1023 - 400)*100 = (100*x-40000)/623
```

### C

```
double in = get_value();
double percent = (double)(100*in - 40000.0)/623;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the map function: [map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map)

```
percentage = map(your_value, 400, 1023, 0, 100);
```

Comment: Using map() without thinking what really happens behind the scenes can lead to wrong Arduino sketch behaviour, see https://www.jetmore.org/john/blog/2011/09/arduinos-map-function-and-numeric-distribution/ which after years of discussion still does not appear as an addendum to the Arduino map() function documentation.

Answer (score 0):

arduino has actually a built in function for this because the ADC values always need conversion to a human form.

[check here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/map)